# Make a moving cursor using doubly linked list in java

Tags: java, data-structures, time-complexity, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to write a code for a simple moving cursor in java. I have to use doubly linked list. Also I should implement doubyLinkedList class myself. In this program  first we take an integer like `n` from user as number of lines. Then we take n lines of input. Each line contains only one character which can be `<` or `>` or `-` or one of the lower case English alphabet. For `>` or `<` we move the cursor to right or left. For `-` we delete the character in the place of cursor. For alphabets we add them to the doubly linked list. At last we print the result in one line without spaces. I have made the doubyLinkedList class and needed methods. I think it is working properly but the time complexity of the code must be `O(n)`. I guess it's `O(n^2)` now.

```
import java.util.*;
public class DoublyLinkedList {
static Node head = null;
static int size = 0;
class Node {
    String data;
    Node prev;
    Node next;
    Node(String d) {
        data = d;
    }
}
static Node deleteNode(Node del) {
    if (head == null || del == null)
        return null;
    if (head == del)
        head = del.next;
    if (del.next != null)
        del.next.prev = del.prev;
    if (del.prev != null)
        del.prev.next = del.next;
    del = null;
    size --;
    return head;
}
public String GetNth(int index) {
    Node current = head;
    int count = 0;
    while (current != null)
    { if (count == index)
        return current.data;
        count++;
        current = current.next;
    }
    assert (false);
    return null;
}
public static void deleteNodeAtGivenPos(int n) {
    size--;
    if (head == null || n <= 0)
        return;
    Node current = head;
    int i;
    for (i = 1; current != null && i < n; i++)
        current = current.next;
    if (current == null)
        return;
    deleteNode(current);
}
void insertFirst (String data){
    size++;
    Node newNode = new Node(data);
    if (head == null) {
        newNode.prev = null;
        head = newNode;
        return;
    }
    else
        head.prev= newNode;
    newNode.next=head;
    head = newNode;
}
void append(String data) {
    size++;
    Node newNode = new Node(data);
    Node last = head;
    newNode.next = null;
    if (head == null) {
        newNode.prev = null;
        head = newNode;
        return;
    }
    while (last.next != null)
        last = last.next;
    last.next = newNode;
    newNode.prev = last;
}
public void insertAtGivenPos(String s , int index){
    Node newNode= new Node(s);
    Node current= head;
    if (index==0)
        insertFirst(s);
    else if(index==size)
        append(s);
    else{
        for(int j = 0; j < index && current.next != null; j++){
            current = current.next;
        }
        newNode.next = current;
        current.prev.next = newNode;
        newNode.prev = current.prev;
        current.prev = newNode;
        size++;
    }
}
public void print(Node node) {
    while (node != null) {
        System.out.print(node.data + "");
        node = node.next;
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    String [] arr= new String[n];
    for (int i=0; i< n; i++)
        arr[i] = sc.nextLine();
    DoublyLinkedList dll = new DoublyLinkedList();
    int cursor= 0;
    for (int i=0; i< n; i++){
        if (arr[i].matches("[a-z]")){
            dll.insertAtGivenPos(arr[i], cursor);
            cursor++;
        }
        else if (arr[i].contains("-")&& dll.GetNth(cursor-1)!= null) {
            dll.deleteNodeAtGivenPos(cursor);
            cursor--;
        }
        else if (arr[i].contains("<") && dll.GetNth(cursor-1)!= null)
            cursor--;
        else if (arr[i].contains(">") && dll.GetNth(cursor+1)!= null)
            cursor++;
    }
    dll.print(dll.head);
}
}
```

How can I improve my code to reduce time complexity?

**Edit**: Also I understood that my code is giving wrong answer for some cases. Could you help me debug it?

Comment: I'm thinking about improving methods of my class. Like the methods for inserting and deleting node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not forced to follow implementation details, I suggest not to have a cursor. Instead, keep a variable `currentNode` which is the node that the `cursor` would point to. So for every command (or data) in the input loop, you have one O(1) operation as bellow and hence will get O(n) time complexity.

> **1 -** for `>` : change the `currentNode` to `currentNode.next`
>
> **2 -** for `<` do the reverse
>
> **3 -** for `-` change the previous and the next node of `currentNode` to
> point to each other (so the current is deleted)
>
> **4 -** and finally for insertion : create a node and like `3`, change the
> the side nodes to point to it

Comment: Using this method I could write the code which takes linear time. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need inner for loop. process the input as soon as as you accept it.

```
for (int i=0; i< n; i++)
    arr[i] = sc.nextLine();
    DoublyLinkedList dll = new DoublyLinkedList();
    int cursor= 0;
    if (arr[i].matches("[a-z]")){
        dll.insertAtGivenPos(arr[i], cursor);
        cursor++;
    }
    else if (arr[i].contains("-")&& dll.GetNth(cursor-1)!= null) {
        dll.deleteNodeAtGivenPos(cursor);
        cursor--;
    }
    else if (arr[i].contains("<") && dll.GetNth(cursor-1)!= null)
        cursor--;
    else if (arr[i].contains(">") && dll.GetNth(cursor+1)!= null)
        cursor++;
}
```

Comment: This reduces the time but I guess it doesn't change the time complexity.